# Declare variable in a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if is possible to create variables inside a sql select query.
Explanation in the following sample, where we select the news from a city published /or updated in the past month (or older):

```
set @monthBack = 1; -- one month back in time
set @cityName = "Berlin"; -- take a city name

select n.title, coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate) as news_date 
from news as n
inner join with cities as c on c.id = n.cityid
where 
    c.name = @cityName and
    year(coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate)) = 
                                 year(current_date - interval @monthBack month)
    month(coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate)) = 
                                 month(current_date - interval @monthBack month)
order by coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate)
```

If a publication date is not defined, the news date will be the updated date.

So, I would like to replace the repetition of the `coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate)` by a specific variable that is specific to the concrete select statement...

Is it possible in the mysql database?

PS.

*As the "problem" is more about sql syntax and code readability, I would like to resolve it just by modifying the sql code, but not applying to external tools or creating additional objects like views or tables (does not worth such complexity for some syntactic optimization)*

Comment: Coalesce is evaluating two values and returning a single value.  Ergo, it is acting just like a function would.  A variable would hold a value for later reference.   In the context of a multi-row select statement, there is no opportunity to 'store, then later retrieve' a variable value.  The coalesce must carry out its function for every row.   You could convert to using a cursor and variable(s) if absolutely compelled to use a variable.  But a cursor would be slower and less optimal for maintenance reasons.   If your query is working, just go with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of many ways to resolve your problems but I'm not sure wich one is the best.

You could do a ";With" subquery to determine the value of "coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate)" and then use it in the query below.

Or use a stored procedure ou function wich recive the right parameters

You could do a view on your table news and add a column wich is the value of "coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate)"

Or you can also do something like :

```
set @monthBack = 1; -- one month back in time
DECLARE @Query NVarchar(Max),
        @NewsDate NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @NewsDate = coalesce (n.releaseDate, n.updateDate) -- Determine the value here

SET @Query = 
'select n.title, '+@NewsDate+' as news_date 
 from news as n
 inner join with cities as c on c.id = n.cityid
 where 
     c.name='Berlin' and
     year('+@NewsDate+') = 
                                  year(current_date - interval @monthBack month)
     month('+@NewsDate+')) = 
                                  month(current_date - interval @monthBack month)
 order by '+@NewsDate

execute sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: The OP is using mysql not ms-sql. Don't think you can do "exeute sp_executesql @Query" in mysql.

Comment: merci, Danielle, I updated in a PS the question to be more clear about solutions...